# NGRX Select: How is the selection working with an inner object?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

i am new to NGRX and try to get running a simple NGRX example. I have an interface called LoginState, which is the Object in my Store. The LoginState contains a user object of type IUser. If i select on this object in my component, i don't get returned the IUser, if the user object changes (my effects seem to work fine, because if i just do a subscribe on the store, i get returned all state changes).

Here my configuration:

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot({loginState: loginReducer})
]
```

**login.actions.ts**

```
export const userLoginRequest = createAction('[Login] user login request');
export const userLoginFacebookSuccess = createAction('[Login] user login facebook success', props<{socialUser: SocialUser}>());
export const userLoginSuccess = createAction('[Login] user login success', props<{user: IUser}>());
```

**login.reducer.ts**

```
export interface LoginState {
    request: boolean;
    socialUser?: SocialUser;
    user?: IUser;
}

export const initialState: LoginState = {
    request: false
};

const reducer = createReducer(initialState,
    on(userLoginRequest, (status, action) => ({
        ...status,
        request: true
     })),
    on(userLoginFacebookSuccess, (status, action) => ({
        ...status,
        socialUser: action.socialUser
    })),
    on(userLoginSuccess, (status, action) => ({
        ...status,
        user: action.user
    }))
);

export function loginReducer(sta: LoginState, action: Action): LoginState {
    return reducer(sta, action);
}
```

login.effects.ts

```
import { userLoginRequest, userLoginSuccess, userLoginFacebookSuccess } from './login.action';

@Injectable()
export class LoginEffects {

loginFacebook$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(userLoginRequest),
    switchMap(() =>
        this.authService.loginFacebook()
            .pipe(
                 map((socialUser) => {
                     this.tokenService.saveToken(socialUser.authToken);
                     return userLoginFacebookSuccess({socialUser});
                 })
            )
        )
     )
 );

loadUser$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(userLoginFacebookSuccess),
    switchMap((act) =>
        this.userService.getUser(act.socialUser)
            .pipe(
                map((usr) => userLoginSuccess({user: usr}))
            )
        )
    )
);


constructor(
  private actions$: Actions,
  private authService: AuthWrapperService,
  private tokenService: TokenStorageService,
  private userService: UserService
) {}

}
```

**Login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

localUser: IUser;

constructor(
          private router: Router,
          private store: Store<LoginState>
){}

signInWithFB(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(userLoginRequest());
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select(selectUser).subscribe( (user) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user, undefined, 2));
}
);
}
}

const loginState = (state: LoginState) => state;

export const selectUser = createSelector(
  loginState,
  (state: LoginState) => state.user
);
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Cheers,

Tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you have is fine, you need to keep in mind that `ngrx` selects data instantly, even you don't have it.

Therefore when `this.store.select(selectUser)` is executed very first time before the use has been loaded it will return undefined, it's expected.

When `userLoginSuccess` has been processed we have a user in the store and the selector will emit the second value that is desired user.

You can filter emits in a stream if you expect always to get a user. Also please note that your state is under `loginState`, therefore you need to use `createFeatureSelector`.

```js
const loginStateFeature = createFeatureSelector<LoginState>('loginState');

export const selectUser = createSelector(
  loginStateFeature,
  (state: LoginState) => state.user
);


ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select(selectUser).pipe(
    filter(user => !!user), // skipping falsy emits.
  ).subscribe((user) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user, undefined, 2));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But exactly here is the problem. The selector doesn't get called after my user is updated. Any idea why?

Comment: Ah true, you need to change `selectUser`, I've updated the answer how to change it.

Comment: i am trying the same but i want to select specific array within User, so therefore i want to select property within user, but i get undefined error always